# vba In excel if condition or nested if

Tags: excel, vba

hey i want to check **data in F** row is **0** or not while ***entering data in G row*** If data in F row has value 0 than one msgbox pop-up and alert me as popup msg?

Comment: what have you already tried? Any code?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have and what the code you are working with is?

Comment: And also read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to loop through everything.

```
Dim lastRow As String
Dim x as Long

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To lastRow
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & x) = 0 Then msgBox ("Zero Value" & x)
    Else (Add your else here, or drop the else and get get pinged every time you hit zero)
Next
```

This will loop through every row in your sheet